# how to open WifiDisplay Setting from another app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to open Android4.2 setting WifiDisplaySettingsActivity from my app.

I tried

```
        Intent i;
        PackageManager manager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        try {
            i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.settings.wfd");
            if (i == null)
                throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
            i.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        }
```

and

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings.wfd","com.android.settings.wfd.WifiDisplaySettings");
    intent.setComponent(cn);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

but none of them could work.
I went to the AndroidManifest.xml to see code

```
        <activity android:name="Settings$WifiDisplaySettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/wifi_display_settings_title"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="com.android.settings.FRAGMENT_CLASS"
            android:value="com.android.settings.wfd.WifiDisplaySettings" />
    </activity>
```

the question is I know it's a fragment class and I know it's package name is com.android.settings.wfd, but I still don't know how to open it,  especially I don't know how to handle activity name like this

> Settings$WifiDisplaySettingsActivity

Can some one give me 
advices???plz....thank you very much

the problem is it's settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS but not ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS, so the eclipse can't compile

addional:

```
public final class WifiDisplaySettings extends SettingsPreferenceFragment implements PersistentGroupInfoListener {
private static final String TAG = "WifiDisplaySettings";

private static final int MENU_ID_SCAN = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int MENU_ID_CREATE_GROUP = Menu.FIRST + 1;
private static final int MENU_ID_REMOVE_GROUP = Menu.FIRST + 2;
```

it's Setting Preference Fragment ... so how do I open it???

Answer (score 2):

Wireless Display Settings activity can be called through the Intent `"android.settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS".`
Some OEMs use other intents

Samsung: `"com.samsung.wfd.LAUNCH_WFD_PICKER_DLG"`

HTC: `"com.htc.wifidisplay.CONFIGURE_MODE_NORMAL"`

so, not guaranteed to work.

I dealt with the same issue and ended up with the following code.

```
try {
  Log.d("TAG", "open WiFi display settings in HTC");
  godController.getActivity().startActivity(new 
             Intent("com.htc.wifidisplay.CONFIGURE_MODE_NORMAL"));
} catch (Exception e) {
  try {
    Log.d("TAG", "open WiFi display settings in Samsung");
    godController.getActivity().startActivity(new 
              Intent("com.samsung.wfd.LAUNCH_WFD_PICKER_DLG"));
  } catch (Exception e2) {
    Log.d("TAG", "open WiFi display settings in stock Android");
    godController.getActivity().startActivity(new 
               Intent("android.settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS"));
  }
}
```

Please let me know if it can be better implemented.

Comment: How did you go about discovering these non-standard settings panels? I need to find the miracast settings panel for an Xperia Z3

Comment: You do not see these Intent View Action Strings in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.htm

Answer (score 1):

startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS"));

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(MainActivity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
/*
 * 3G confirm
 */
Boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(
        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();
/*
 * wifi confirm
 */
Boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(
        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();
if (is3g) {
    textView.setText("3G");
} else if (isWifi) {
    textView.setText("wifi");
} else {
    textView.setText("nothing");
    // Activity transfer to wifi settings
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
}
```

This may help you

Comment: ???, I mean I just want to start the Android setting app, but not connect to wifi.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

Or

```
public void openWifiSettings(){

        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");
        intent.setComponent(cn);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity( intent);
    }
```

Comment: I tried, but nope not working..It gets to the Wi-Fi setting page, but not Wi-Display page

Comment: thanks men...but the problem is it's settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS
but not ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS, so the eclipse can't compile