# No activity found for intent with action android.settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS

Tags: android, settings

I need to make intent in my app with going into cast screen options. Here is my code:

```
public static final String ACTION_WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS = "android.settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS";

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(ACTION_WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);

              }

            }
        });
```

But after compiling code and pressing button it was a crash with log:

ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS }
I tested this code on nexus 5 (android 6.0) and nexus 4 (android 4.3).

so, how i can to make intent to wireless display settings ?

Comment: Did you tried this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22112983/1380032

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_CAST_SETTINGS